# JavaFX - List of custom controls inside another custom control using FXML

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls, fxml, observablelist

I want to create a custom control in which I can set a list of another custom controls, and I want to be able to use FXML just like it is possible to do in the JavaFX TableView (see the list of columns):

## JavaFX TableView

### TableView.fxml

```xml
<TableView fx:id="tableView">

    <columns>

        <TableColumn>...</TableColumn>

        <TableColumn>...</TableColumn>

      ...
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

### TableView.java

```java
public class FXMLTableViewController {

    @FXML TableView<MyBean> tableView;

    private void myMethod1() {
        ObservableList<TableColumn<MyBean, ?>> columns = tableView.getColumns();
        ...

    }
}
```

I just want to write something like:

## CustomControl1

### CustomControl1.fxml

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.Control" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"> 
   <customList>

       <CustomControl2>
           ...
       </CustomControl2>

       <CustomControl2>
           ...
       </CustomControl2>

       ...

   </customList>
</fx:root>
```

### CustomControl1.java

```java
public class CustomControl1 extends Control {

    private ObservableList<CustomControl2> controls2;

    public CustomControl1() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
        FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomControl1.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();            
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    private void myMethod1() {
        controls2 = getControls2();
        ...
    }
}
```

I already know how to implement simple custom controls, but I have not found anything about composing custom controls this way. Can you point me some direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the real type of the class in the `<fx:root>` element, since `Control` does not provide `customList`. I.e. use something like `type="my.package.CustomControl1"`.

Furthermore to add elements the way `TableView` allows you to do the class created for the surrounding tag needs to provide a readonly list property with the name of the tag, i.e.

```
public class CustomControl1 extends Control {

    ...

    public ObservableList<CustomControl2> getCustomList() {
        return controls2;
    }

}
```

Comment: So the class CustomControl1 will be at the same time the type and the controller of the fx:root element? It is allowed, since the class is defining this element?